# Adding support for Swift Package Manager doesn't build correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to add support for Swift Package Manager, and running into a roadblock.  I've created the `Package.swift` file, committed it, and tried adding the package to a sample app.  But I get errors around `MyLibrary_MyLibrary.bundle: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable. Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code`.

I noticed when building the sample app that in the DerivedData build folder, the only file for my package is that `{libraryName}_{MyLibrary}.bundle` file, it doesn't include a `.swiftmodule` folder, and thinking that is causing problems.  Why wouldn't it include that when building?

Package.swift file for library

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v10), .macOS("10.11"), .tvOS(.v9)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/dependency1/dependency1", .exact("1.0.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/dependency2/dependency2", .exact("1.0.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/dependency3/dependency3", .exact("1.0.0")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            dependencies: ["Dependency1", "Dependency2", "Dependency3"],
            path: "./my-library/",
            exclude: ["Info.plist"]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "my-library-swiftTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLibrary"],
            path: "./my-library-swiftTests/",
            exclude: ["Info.plist"],
            resources: [
                .copy("Fixtures")
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when trying to add a resources directory to the tests target. I was using `.copy("MyResourceFolder")`. Changing this to copy each individual resource explicitly fixed this for me, e.g:

```
.copy("MyResourceFolder/test1.json"),
.copy("MyResourceFolder/test2.json"),
```